# Azure Functions: Cannot find module '@azure/cosmos'

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

I'm using the local git to deploy azure functions.

I run `npm install @azure/cosmos` and installed @azure/cosmos locally.

I pushed my code to Azure.

When I execute that function, the error message says "Cannot find module '@azure/cosmos'".

Why?

My function code is:

```
const { CosmosClient } = require("@azure/cosmos")
module.exports = async function (context) {};
```

The following code doesn't raise an error:

```
const { v4: uuid } = require('uuid')
module.exports = async function (context) {};
```

My package.json is:

```
{

  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/cosmos": "^3.11.3",
    "azure-storage": "^2.10.4",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Comment: Please add some Azure function code, is function written in JS & using `azure/cosmos` package?

Comment: Can [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-add-output-binding-cosmos-db-vs-code?pivots=programming-language-javascript) help you?

Comment: @TinyWang I read it but could not fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

I run `rm -r ./node_modules` via SSH in Azure portal and rerun `git push`. Then, @azure/cosmos was installed.